# how do I configure CodeIgniter to open the a controller that is in another folder but with only domain name

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

Ok, so I have a page '*example.com*' and I have a folder that contains all my code that I have been debugin in my localhost.

So my localhost route is localhost/sistem but I want to upload my folder to my domain server at '*example.com*' but the route would then be example.com/sistem

I want to make a route to not show '*sistem*' at all; that when I access '*example.com*' I directly go into sistem without sistem apearring in the URL

```
example.com /*server*/
    sistem/ /*root folder*/
        login.php /*which has the index*/
        other.php
        other2.php
```

what I want is the URL to be example.com but to show login.php's index function.

I know i use

```
$route['default_controller'] = "login”;
```

but that opens after I access '*example.com/sistem*'

Comment: Set your base url to example.com . Put the main index.php file at the server root level. In the index.php declare the path to your application and system folders. speaking of the app and system folders - put them above the system root if that is possible for security.

Answer (score 0):

Add it in your route configuration:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "sistem/login”

$route['sistem/'] = FALSE;     // Show 404
$route['sistem/(:any)'] = FALSE; // Show 404
$route['(:any)'] = 'sistem/$1';
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'sistem/$1/$2';
```

Comment: I supose that *$1* would be *login* can you explain what **(:any)/(:any)** and **(:any)** does @Medet

Comment: ** (:any)** means controller name. When you write example.com/login, it means call *login* controller that is inside of sistem folder.

Comment: *(:any)/(:any)* means, first :any is controller name, and second one is function name inside of sistem. For example calling `http://example.com/other/method` will route to `sistem/other[.php]/method`

Comment: your answer doesn't work. I got lost. this is what I have so far
`echo $base_url = base_url();
$base_url/sistem_folder/controller/method
$route['404_override'] = '';

$route['default_controller'] = "$base_url/folder”;

$route['$base_url/'] = FALSE;     // Show 404
$route['$base_url/(:any)'] = FALSE; // Show 404
$route['(:any)'] = '$base_url/folder';

$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = '$base_url/folder/controller';`